# Symfony2 can't find route for an action

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm doing a bundle with google drive api that lists files. I have in the IndexAction an if that sees if the user needs to give permission or already gave. If needs, then I get the url from google and redirect to that link.

In google console I put as redirect link:

```
www.googlebundle/firstTime
```

In my GoogleDriveController I've got the

```
public function firstTimeAction() {
       (...)
}
```

And in my routing I got this:

```
FilesGoogleDriveBundle_firstTime:
   pattern: /firstTime
   defaults: { _controller: "FilesGoogleDriveBundle:GoogleDrive:firstTime" }
   requirements: { _method: get }

FilesGoogleDriveBundle_homepage:
   pattern:  /Drive/{id}
   defaults: { _controller: FilesGoogleDriveBundle:GoogleDrive:index }
```

But I get this error in prod.log:

```
[2012-11-26 16:50:14] request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /firstTime" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 4564 [] []
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: can you run `php app/console router:debug` and post the output?

Comment: also, did you clear your cache? routes are cached, even in dev.

Comment: Does your .htaccess file properly rewrite `/app.php` to `/`?

Comment: @Squazic considering he has a symfony routing error, it seems like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that symfony see your router rule.

In project root directory put

```
php app/console router:debug | grep FilesGoogleDriveBundle_firstTime
```

You should get something like this

```
FilesGoogleDriveBundle_firstTime   GET    /firstTime
```

The last value is the URL for this action.

Comment: Know it's working but only when I use `app_dev.php/firstTime` if I put only `/firstTime` I get an error.

Comment: In that case try to clear production cache (as MrGlass wrote)

Answer (score 0):

```
FilesGoogleDriveBundle_firstTime:
   pattern: /firstTime
   defaults: { _controller: FilesGoogleDriveBundle:GoogleDrive:firstTime }
   requirements: 
       _method: GET
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a cache problem, clear the cache for the prod environment:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```